# XCode 3.2.6 cannot build the app to the device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I just downloaded the new xcode, 3.2.6 to try with the new sdk. I don't want to try with Xcode 4 yet, because it requires some learning curve that I cannot do it right now. The problem with my new xcode is that I cannot build and install the app to the device. I tried creating a brand new project but xcode cannot install into my device. Here is the log, I have no idea about what I should do after reading the log:

```
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
gdb stack trace at 'putpkt: write failed':
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00190e1e remote_backtrace_self + 54�
1   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00194236 putpkt_binary + 401�
2   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00194933 remote_macosx_get_all_image_infos_addr + 45�
3   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00199584 remote_macosx_complete_create_or_attach + 146�
4   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00199d09 remote_macosx_create_inferior + 1273�
5   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0006ffb1 run_command_1 + 660�
6   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0012fc05 execute_command + 724�
7   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0001c0cf mi_execute_async_cli_command + 226�
8   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0001b6ec captured_mi_execute_command + 371�
9   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00085c51 catch_exception + 65�
10  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00018a4a mi_execute_command + 163�
11  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00018bef mi_execute_command_wrapper + 50�
12  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008b639 handle_file_event + 349�
13  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008b000 process_event + 131�
14  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008bdba gdb_do_one_event + 1178�
15  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00085d74 catch_errors + 78�
16  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008b4b1 start_event_loop + 76�
17  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00088227 captured_command_loop + 18�
18  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00085d74 catch_errors + 78�
19  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00088213 captured_main + 5561�
20  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00085d74 catch_errors + 78�
21  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00086c4f gdb_main + 63�
22  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00001cae main + 52�
23  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00001c3d start + 53�
recent remote packets prior to 'putpkt: write failed':
Sent:  [1300637137.584:1306] +
Sent:  [1300637137.584:1306] Hc-1
Recvd: [1300637137.586:1306] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.586:1306] qC
Recvd: [1300637137.589:1306] QC0
Sent:  [1300637137.589:1306] qStepPacketSupported
Recvd: [1300637137.591:1306] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.662:1317] QEnvironment:SHELL=/bin/bash
Recvd: [1300637137.664:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.664:1317] QEnvironment:TMPDIR=/var/folders/pu/pusl0+euEjCbaQgqND99RU+++TI/-Tmp-/
Recvd: [1300637137.665:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.665:1317] QEnvironment:Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-HWaO4c/Render
Recvd: [1300637137.668:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.668:1317] QEnvironment:USER=vodkhang
Recvd: [1300637137.669:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.669:1317] QEnvironment:COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Recvd: [1300637137.671:1317] OK
putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe
putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
Sent:  [1300637137.671:1317] QEnvironment:SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-M9d1p5/Listeners
Recvd: [1300637137.673:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.673:1317] QEnvironment:__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Recvd: [1300637137.674:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.674:1317] QEnvironment:PATH=/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Recvd: [1300637137.676:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.676:1317] QEnvironment:PWD=/Users/vodkhang/SlowPerformanceTableView/build/Debug-iphoneos
Recvd: [1300637137.678:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.678:1317] QEnvironment:SSH_ASKPASS=/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework/Resources/Xcode SSHPassKey
Recvd: [1300637137.679:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.679:1317] QEnvironment:SHLVL=0
Recvd: [1300637137.681:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.681:1317] QEnvironment:HOME=/Users/vodkhang
Recvd: [1300637137.682:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.682:1317] QEnvironment:LOGNAME=vodkhang
Recvd: [1300637137.684:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.684:1317] QEnvironment:DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-Ie16lR/org.x:0
Recvd: [1300637137.685:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.685:1317] QEnvironment:LINES=24
Recvd: [1300637137.687:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.687:1317] QEnvironment:COLUMNS=80
Recvd: [1300637137.688:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.688:1317] QEnvironment:DYLD_NEW_LOCAL_SHARED_REGIONS=YES
Recvd: [1300637137.690:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.690:1317] QEnvironment:USERBREAK=1
Recvd: [1300637137.691:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.691:1317] QEnvironment:NSUnbufferedIO=YES
Recvd: [1300637137.693:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.693:1317] QEnvironment:DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING=YES
Recvd: [1300637137.694:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.694:1317] QEnvironment:DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/vodkhang/SlowPerformanceTableView/build/Debug-iphoneos
Recvd: [1300637137.696:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.696:1317] QEnvironment:DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/vodkhang/SlowPerformanceTableView/build/Debug-iphoneos
Recvd: [1300637137.698:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.698:1317] QSetDisableASLR:1
Recvd: [1300637137.699:1317]  
Sent:  [1300637137.699:1317] A246,0,2f707269766174652f7661722f6d6f62696c652f4170706c69636174696f6e732f36453541383039342d393035322d344133462d423634442d4630304233414537363246392f536c6f77506572666f726d616e63655461626c65566965772e6170702f536c6f77506572666f726d616e63655461626c6556696577
Recvd: [1300637137.702:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637137.702:1317] qLaunchSuccess
Sent:  [1300637167.704:1317] qLaunchSuccess
Recvd: [1300637167.886:1317] OK
Sent:  [1300637167.886:1317] +
Sent:  [1300637167.886:1317] qC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting the device alone fixes the issue.

I have had a few "broken pipe" errors before and restarting the device fixed it.

Comment: I tried everything excep restarting the device, let me try it

Comment: this error is pretty annoying. I have to restart the device at least 20 times a day...

Comment: How can we test automatic lightweight migration between versions when something like this happens? It is not feasible to delete the app in that case. How do we know when we deploy our new app to multitudes of people it will not crash?

Comment: @JPK - This doesn't cause crashes. It is still during the write (install) phase.